# converting unicode to datetime in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

This should be an easy one but I am new to using datetime ...

I want to convert the following unicode to any usable datetime format:
u'Tuesday, March 28, 2017'

So I have:

```
>> from datetime import datetime
>> test = u'Tuesday, March 28, 2017'
>> date_time = datetime.strptime(test, '????')
```

I have tried a bunch of combinations for '????' but I keep getting an error saying that the format does not match.  I am looking for one working example of '????' to get the unicode date into datetime type and then I can mess with the format to get it that way I want it in datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have trouble figuring out what `datetime.strptime()` specifications work for your date, *break down the date into components*. It is much easier to puzzle out a single specification per component.

So for your date, start perhaps with the `March 28` component (*just* Tuesday is very ambiguous, nor is it very unique to a date):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('March 28', '%B %d')  # Full month and numeric day
datetime.datetime(1900, 3, 28, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('March 28, ', '%B %d, ')  # add in the comma and space
datetime.datetime(1900, 3, 28, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('March 28, 2017', '%B %d, %Y')  # add in the year
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 28, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime(', March 28, 2017', ', %B %d, %Y')  # another comma and space
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 28, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('Tuesday, March 28, 2017', '%A, %B %d, %Y')  # Full weekday name
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 28, 0, 0)
```

So `'%A, %B %d, %Y'` matches the string you tried to parse.

Comment: Thanks!  It was the commas which were throwing me off, and now I see you just include them in the format argument in the same way they appear in the original unicode.

Comment: @mmalek: had you included one of your failed attempts with an explanation as to why you thought it ought to have worked, I could have written an answer detailing *that*. In future, please do include your actual attempts, even if they didn't work, and your thinking; that is much easier to correct than a generic 'what do I put here' set of question marks.